# Dynamic python user input to a seperate C program

Tags: python, c, input

I have a python GUI interface written in Tkinter. The main point of the program is to setup many different variables for a final calculation on a hyperspectral image (geography stuff). Now, some further specifications have developed where the user would like to be able to actively input some parameters for groups of pixels to be smoothed. This information would be input in the Python GUI and the C programs that handle the image modifications need this as input. Since the images can be giant, I want to try and avoid always re-running the C program (which involves memory allocation, reading a giant file, etc.) with a call such as

```
os.system(./my_C_Program param1 param2 param3....)
```

I'd prefer to have a system where once I've called `my_C_Program`, it can be in a state of waiting after having loaded all the resources into memory. I was thinking something involving `getchar()` would be what I want, but I don't know how I can get the output from python to go `my_C_Program`. I've seen a few similar questions about this on SO, but I wasn't able to determine quite how those scenarios would help mine specifically.

If `getchar()` is the answer, can someone please explain how stdout works with multiple terminals open?

As well, I'm trying to keep this program easily multiplatform across linux/mac/windows.

To summarize, I want the following functionality:

1. User selects certain input from python GUI
2. That input becomes the input for a C program
3. That C program can handle more input without having to be run again from the start (avoiding file I/O, etc).

Comment: Do you have control over the design and implementation of the C program in addition to the Python program? Or is its implementation set in stone?

Comment: I have full control of the C program design/code. This idea of connecting different programs in different languages is quite new to me.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you should probably do is start using [Python's `subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html), rather than [`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system). Once you've done that, then you can change it so the C program's `stdin` is something you can write to in Python, rather than inheriting the Python script's `stdin`.

After that, you could just have Python send data over that the C program can interpret. For example, you might want to use a bunch of JSON chunks, one per line, like [Twitter's streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/concepts#parsing-responses)<sup>1</sup>; the Python script makes a request dictionary, serializes it with [`json.dump`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.dump), and then writes a newline. The C program reads a line, parses the JSON, and handles the request.

<sup>1</sup> Upon reading the documentation, it looks like their implementation is a little more complex. You could adopt how they do it or just do it like I described.

Comment: I'm trying some stuff with subprocess right now, and I'm finding it that it seems to block when executing my C program. For example if my C program was something like this:

    `char x = getchar();
while(x != 'q'){
 x = getchar();
 if(x == 'a') {
  myMethod(); 
 }
}`

and my python program is:


`p = sp.Popen("./my_C_Program")
p.communicate(input = 'a')`


As soon as the call to `communicate` is made, my python is blocked from continuing. Is there a way to make the C program run without blocking the python?

Comment: really sorry about the editing, I couldn't get the code to be blocked properly

Comment: @Ponml: If you make sure to redirect the `stdin` (pass `stdin=sp.PIPE` into `Popen`, too) and skip `communicate` and use `p.stdin.write(...)` then it shouldn't block.

Answer (score 3):

[icktoofay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9424894/377270) and [JasonFruit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9424875/377270) have suggested decent approaches; I'm going to suggest something to decouple the two programs a little further.

If you write your C program as a *server* that listens for requests and replies with answers on a TCP socket, you can more easily change clients, make it support multiple simultaneous clients, perform near-seamless upgrades of clients or servers without necessarily needing to modify the other, or you could move the C program to more powerful hardware without needing to do more than slightly modify configurations.

Once you have opened a listening socket and accepted a connection, the rest of your program could continue as if you were just interacting over standard input and standard output. This works well enough, but you might prefer to encode your data in some standardized format such as [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asn1), which can save some manual string handling.

Comment: +1 I'd also go with the networking approach - seems easier in the long run and less fragile.

Answer (score 2):

Could you do something with [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect)?  It lets you provide input to a command-line program, waiting for specified prompts from it before continuing.  It also lets you read the intervening output, so you could respond to that as needed.

If you're on Windows (as I note from your comment that you are), you could try [winpexpect](https://bitbucket.org/geertj/winpexpect/wiki/Home), which is similar.

Comment: I saw this while digging through SO, but it appears to not have direct Windows support. Perhaps that's changed since what I was reading? I am trying to figure out more on it now.

Comment: Try [WExpect](https://bitbucket.org/geertj/winpexpect/wiki/Home).  I didn't know you were on Windows.

Comment: Apparently, its name has changed to winpexpect.